# How do I run Sonar Runner with custom property file name? Example: sonar-project-abc.properties

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to run Sonar on my javascript project
but its giving me an error. Can you please help me out as how to run Sonar with custom property file name

```
C:\sonar-runner-2.4\bin\..
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.8.0_25 Oracle Corporation (32-bit)
Windows 7 6.1 x86
INFO: Runner configuration file: C:\sonar-runner-2.4\bin\..\conf\sonar-runner.pr
operties
INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is
 platform dependent)
INFO: Work directory: C:\Users\FS00341311\Workspaces\8\app\usage\.\.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.2
20:51:13.338 INFO  - Load global repositories
20:51:13.464 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=124ms
20:51:13.477 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\FS00341311\.sonar\cache
20:51:14.531 INFO  - Load plugins index
20:51:14.537 INFO  - Load plugins index (done) | time=6ms
20:51:14.734 INFO  - Process project properties
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2.113s
Final Memory: 6M/73M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknow
n': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources
ERROR:
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with t
he -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: Did you have a loot at [this](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScanner-Usage) page?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a project.settings property

```
sonar-scanner -Dproject.settings=sonar-project-abc.properties
```

see https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Advanced+SonarQube+Scanner+Usages